# How can I solve this question using the 1 in 60 rule?

Tags: navigation, ppl, student-pilot

What is the explanation for the question below in detail?

> A pilot is heading east and decides to fly to an alternate airfield which is 4NM south and currently 30NM from his present position. What is the new track to arrive at the alternate airfield?
>
> - A - TRK 008°
> - B - TRK 098°
> - C - TRK 100°
>
> Answer: B

I can't understand how the 1 in 60 rule would be applied to solve this here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question indicates the answer is "B" and you want to understand how to apply the 1 in 60 rule to get this answer.  See the diagram below for an explanation:

**1 in 60 rule**: ([Source)](https://skybrary.aero/articles/rules-thumb)

> A 1 degree offset angle at 60 nm equates to 1 nm of displacement.

[image]

Comment: how accurate is that rule of thumb as you go to 90 degrees?  :)

Comment: hi @RTO !  :) it was a math joke  :)

Comment: hi @RTO , sorry you may be misunderstanding me.  My original comment (*".. what happens as you go to 90 degrees?!"*) is a joke; it's a joke any mathematician would understand. Cheers!